# Jquery .onclick POST var using ajax and receiving data from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying this:
- Onclick on button get **this.data-id** as id in a DB select
- These data will be dynamically shown in a modal

What I dont know is how to work with ajax, can anyone help?

HTML

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="'.$method['id'].'" title="Visualizar" class="itemview btn btn-info btn-mini" href="#MethodView">Visualizar</a>
```

.php

```
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] > 0){
            $id=$_POST['id'];
            GetPaymentMethodView();
        }
    }
    function GetPaymentMethodView() {
        global $db;
        try{
            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM payment_methods WHERE id=$id");
            $row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            $result['success'] = true;
            $result['result'] = $row;
            echo json_encode($result);
        return true;
        } catch (PDOException $pe) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

.js

```
$('.itemview').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var uid = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "resources/controllers/get.php",
        data: 'id='+uid,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                console.log(data.result);
                console.log(data.result.id);
            } else {
                alert("error");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In page where you want to display result put something like this

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

In try small modification

```
try{
            $query = $db->query("SELECT id, name, bank_info FROM payment_methods WHERE id=$id");
            $row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            $result['success'] = true;
            $result['result'] = $row;
            echo json_encode($result);
            exit;
        return true;
        }
```

In js small editing

```
success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                //How to show rows in php?
               console.log(data.result);
               console.log(data.result.id);

                var result = data.result;
                //prepare markup
                var resultHtml = '';
                resultHtml += '<p>Id = ' + result.id +'</p>';
                resultHtml += '<p>Name = ' + result.name +'</p>';
                resultHtml += '<p>Bankinfo = ' + result.bank_info  +'</p>';

                //Put markup in div
                $(".result").html(resultHtml)


            } else {
                alert("error");
            }
        }
```

And see in browser console to understand.

Comment: I don't understand, nothing on log, and modal not oppening anymore

Comment: Really nothing in console

Comment: Hey, its working now.. Sorry. How can I print it in php? Thank you very much!

Comment: you can not print in php but you can display in html using jQuery after ajax success. For this you need to put container in html and after ajax prepare markup and add it by jquery. see my new editt.

Answer (score -1):

As both code is in same page you can perform this without js/jQuery too, for that just add value of `$method['id']` directly to `<input>`.

See below to understand

Remove value of `$method['id']` from `<a>` tag

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="" title="Visualizar" class="itemview btn btn-info btn-mini" href="#MethodView">Visualizar</a>
```

Add value directly to `<input>` tag

```
<input type="text" name="methodid" id="methodid" value = "<?php echo $method['id']; ?>" />
```

And problem solved without js. :) So remove js stuff.

Comment: But how will I do an 'auto' SELECT on DB using this id?

Comment: For this you need to use Ajax.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this and return these rows. I will search about it, thanks